# React-select outputting a malformed array in a React.js Redux Firebase application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-select

I've got a React Redux application that is using the npm package react-select with a multi-select piece. My problem is that it's creating a malformed array that I'm unable to iterate over.

```
this.state.typeOfFruit = [
   0: {label: "label 1", value: "apple"},
   1: {label: "label 2", value: "orange"},
   2: {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
]
```

I want to be able to iterate over it with a basic command right now to start gathering the right infromation.

```
typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
```

I was trying to figure out how to access the malformed array or change the array into something I could access, but thought my question needed to change to how do I use this technology to create a good array.

The code below is a piece of the overall code, but it should cover all the pieces of the issue. If you see any glaring holes, please let me know.

```
class FruitOrderForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       typeOfFuit: [],
     }
   }

const fruitOptions = [
   { value: 'apple', label: 'label 1' },
   { value: 'orange', label: 'label 2' },
   { value: 'banana', label: 'label 3' },
]

handleMultiSelectChange = (typeOfFruit) => {
   this.setState({ typeOfFruit });
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.updateProfile(this.state)
   document.getElementById("fruitOrderForm").reset();
}

render() {
   this.state.typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
   return (
      <div>
        <form id='fruitOrderForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          < Select
            id='typeOfFruit'
            value={this.state.typeOfFruit}
            onChange={this.handleMultiSelectChange}
            options={fruitOptions }
            isMulti='true'
            isSearchable='true'
          />
          <button>Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>
   )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
const profile = state.firebase.profile

return{
   profile: profile,
   auth: state.firebase.auth
} 
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       updateProfile: (users) => dispatch(updateProfile(users)),
    }
}

export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
   firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'users'}]))(
FruitOrderForm)
```

Then it goes to the store redux action

```
export const updateProfile = (users) => {
   return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      const profile = getState().firebase.profile
      const userID = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
      firestore.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
         ...profile,
         typeOfConsulting: users.typeOfConsulting
      }).then(() => {
         dispatch({ type: 'UPDATED_PROFILE', profile });
         console.log('update successful')
      }).catch((err) => {
         dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR', err });
         console.log('There was an error', err)
      })
   }
}
```

Then through the reducer

```
const businessProfileReducter = (state = initState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'CREATE_BUSINESS_PROFILE': 
         console.log('created business profile', action.businessProfile)
         return state;
      case 'CREATE_BUSINES_PROFILE_ERROR': 
         console.log('create business profile error', action.err);
         return state;
     default:
        return state;
   }
}

export default businessProfileReducter;
```

Then the root reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   auth: authReducer,
   businessProfile: businessProfileReducer,
   firestore: firestoreReducer,
   firebase: firebaseReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

What I want to have output by this would be a good array that I can iterate over.

```
this.state.typeOfFruit = [
   {label: "label 1", value: "apple"}
   {label: "label 2", value: "orange"}
   {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
]
```

Comment: When you say that it is outputting a malformed array, what is it that is wrong with the array / what is happening with it that shows that it is malformed?

Comment: @smashed-potatoes It is creating an array like this.

    `this.state.typeOfFruit = [
       0: {label: "label 1", value: "apple"}
       1: {label: "label 2", value: "orange"}
       2: {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
    ]`

I'm unable to iterate over it with the numbers in the front. You can see the array better at the top of my question.

Comment: @CTOverton, just missed putting them into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may actually be getting an object rather than an array (the fact that the keys are shown). If that is the case you can iterate over it with:

```
Object.keys(typeOfFruit).map((fruitId) => console.log(typeOfFruit[fruitId].value))
```

or

```
Object.values(typeOfFruit).map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
```

Comment: I tried the second option that you gave and got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: That sounds like your typeOfFruit state is `undefined` or `null` at some point, in that case you need to wrap it in an empty check (or early return, e.g. `if (!typeOfFruit) return;` prior)

Comment: I can do a console.log(this.state.typeOfFruit) and get the array at the top of my question. So it's not undefined or null. As soon as I try to iterate over it, though, I get  cannot map over undefined

Comment: If you put a break point in prior - what is the value/type of `typeOfFruit` right before the Object.values call in this case?

Comment: If this is going in your render function, you currently have `typeOfFruit.map` without `typeOfFruit` being defined, it should be first extracted from the state or `this.state.typeOfFruit` should be used in its place

Comment: Before I load anything into it, `this.state.typeOfFruit = [];` When I load the first thing into it, `this.state.typeOfFruit = [ {0: {label: "label 1", value: "apple"} ]`

Comment: So you still get the `undefined`/`null` error if you use `Object.values(this.state.typeOfFruit).map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))`?

Comment: It is this.state.typeOfFruit.map in my code. I just missed typing that in here.

Comment: Yes. Still getting Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Definitely strange in that case - there must be something getting your `this.state.typeOfFruit` to be `null`/`undefined` as that call won't give that for arrays, objects, or even strings and numbers

Comment: I've been working on this issue for faaaar too long before posting on here. One of those issues that doesn't make any sense, but it's going to be something stupid simple that fixes it..... I just know it.

Comment: My best recommendation is to set a break point and inspect the value each time your render fires, and possibly each time your setState calls fire. When things get strange, tracing is what usually works for me. If you have an online reproduction of the issue to share I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, @smashed-potatoes. I figured it out based on what we talked about last night. Instead of doing the Object.values where we were originally doing it, I moved it to the onSubmit function. I realized I could pull out the individual values there before it gets sent to Firebase. I added a new array to this.state and then am doing a few operations in the onSubmit function to move it to the proper `this.state.typeOfConsulting` array. See code below. It isn't exactly pretty, but it works!

```
class FruitOrderForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       typeOfFuit: [],
       interimTypeOfFruit: [],     
     }
   }

const fruitOptions = [
   { value: 'apple', label: 'label 1' },
   { value: 'orange', label: 'label 2' },
   { value: 'banana', label: 'label 3' },
]

handleMultiSelectChange = (typeOfFruit) => {
   this.setState({ typeOfFruit });
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
    // I'm setting typeOfFruit to an empty array because otherwise it continues to 
    // push the same values to the array that are already there.
    this.setState({
        typeOfFruit: []
    })
    // Then I'm pushing just the values from this.state.interimTypeOfFruit to the
    // proper this.state.typeOfFruit array that I can access like a regular array
    Object.values(this.state.interimTypeOfFruit).map((fruitType) => {
        this.state.typeOfFruit.push(fruitType.value)
    })
   this.props.updateProfile(this.state)
   document.getElementById("fruitOrderForm").reset();
}

render() {
   this.state.typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
   return (
      <div>
        <form id='fruitOrderForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          < Select
            id='typeOfFruit'
            value={this.state.typeOfFruit}
            onChange={this.handleMultiSelectChange}
            options={fruitOptions }
            isMulti='true'
            isSearchable='true'
          />
          <button>Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>
   )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
const profile = state.firebase.profile

return{
   profile: profile,
   auth: state.firebase.auth
} 
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
       updateProfile: (users) => dispatch(updateProfile(users)),
    }
}

export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
   firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'users'}]))(
FruitOrderForm)
```

I can't upvote your answer as I'm not to a 15 score yet....I marked it as the correct answer, though. Thanks for your help!